# HTML - Using a Media Query to load a separate layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So I am looking for a way to improve my current web design/development workflow/process. Basically I want to design three or four layouts for each page that I make and I want to be able to set a breakpoint which should load a different version of that page.

For example:
I have three pages for the site: home, services and contact and then I have a mobile and tablet version for each of these.

Is it possible to use media queries to load the different html layout based on screen width? I would just use javascript but wanted to know if I might be able to get 'the feel' of media queries?

Thanks for any help

Comment: media query is for loading different style sheets

Comment: I believe you are talking about style sheets. Media Queries are used to load different style sheets. You are trying a responsive webdesign. So you should use one HTML document and different style sheets.

Comment: @1l13v I know that but just wandered if there was a feature to load a different html document with it.

Comment: @JavaForAndroid I am trying to make a responsive design but am designing the base design in photoshop and wanted to know what is the best way to go about this wit photoshop.

Comment: you should have goggled a bit before asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media queries can be used to define specific css rules for a given container based on screen size.

example:

```
#include {
      background-color: blue;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #include {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

in order to load a completely seperate layout, you would have to use either your server side language(php/python ect.) or client side via javascript or jquery. I prefer jquery and it would look something like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $("#include").load("layout-1.html"); 
}
else {
   $("#include").load("layout-2.html");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, as media queries are CSS, and only style existing HTML content.

However, you do have a good amount of play with the layout, and if layout itself is what you need to modify, you can generally rearrange elements on the screen however you wish.

Check out [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for some great examples -- by definition, all the HTML is the same for every iteration, but the site layout changes completely.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use media queries to set display:none/display:block on elements you want to move around and show elsewhere. It's not the ideal solution since it usually involves duplicated code

```
[code] https://jsfiddle.net/b348r3pu/1
```

If you are using angular you might want to use the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead, or someone else said jQuery

Comment: Thanks for that - I guess it could be useful especially for different nav bars etc. for mobile and desktop...I think I would get quite a bit of duplication though....